# How to redirect a sucessful registration to a page template?

Tags: redirect, user-registration

Each time I register I end up in the wp-login page (back-end):

[image]

Is there any way of redirecting the users who register to a page template (front-end)?

Comment: check the available plugins for code samples

Comment: @kaiser what kind of plugins?

Comment: [Redirect Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=redirect&sort=) - Your clients will like it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the filter `registration_redirect` to pass back your own URL, for example;

```php
function wpse_19692_registration_redirect( $url, $result ) {
    $is_error = is_wp_error( $result );

    $user_id = $is_error ? 0 : $result;

    $user = $is_error ? false : get_userdata( $user_id );

    if ( $user ) {
        // Registration success, do something with $user
    }

    return home_url( '/my-page' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_19692_registration_redirect' );
```

Drop it in your `functions.php` or a plugin :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still being redirected to the wp-login back-end :( (I'm working on localhost LAMP, but I don't think that's the reason).

Comment: Are you sure the theme with the code is active? And which version of WP are you running?  It worked fine for me (tested just now, 3.1.3).

Comment: OK it worked after I deactivated bbPress I guess there is a conflict with the plugin. Thanks!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I have a similar question but i'm registering from a page with a custom template that includes a registration form. The redirect isn't working it's taking me back to the main registration page with message to check my email for the password. Can you take a look at my question please. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130560/redirect-to-custom-url-after-registering-from-a-page-with-registration-form

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Is there a way to get the newly registered user_id in this filter? Please advise!

Comment: @karlosuccess See my update

Comment: It works, thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

This is what i use

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user_login" value="Username" id="user_login" class="input" />
<input type="text" name="user_email" value="E-Mail" id="user_email" class="input"  />
<?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="register" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/success"/>
<p class="statement">A password will be e-mailed to you.</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If like me, you use a plugin like [ProfilePress](http://profilepress.net/features/wordpress-front-end-registration-form/) to power/create your WordPress registration form, the following code will automatically log in and redirect registered users to a welcome page.

```
add_action( 'pp_after_registration', 'pp_redirect_after_registration', 10, 3 );

function pp_redirect_after_registration( $form_id, $user_data, $user_id ) {

    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );

    $custom_page_url = 'http://example.com/welcome/';

    wp_redirect( $custom_page_url );
    exit;
}
```

Note: I use the free plugin (https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ppress) version and the above code work both in free and the PRO version.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a plugin for this issue. Also given below is the raw code for a redirect without any plugin.

```
/**
 * Redirect users to custom URL based on their role after login
 **/
function wp_woo_custom_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {

    // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
    $role = $user->roles[0];
    $dashboard = admin_url();
    $myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'my-account' ) );

    if( $role == 'administrator' ) {

        //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
        $admin_redirect = get_option('admin_redirect');
        $redirect = $admin_redirect;
    } elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {

        //Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
        $shop_manager_redirect = get_option('shop_manager_redirect');
        $redirect = $shop_manager_redirect;
    } elseif ( $role == 'customer' || $role == 'subscriber' ) {

        //Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
        $customer_redirect = get_option('customer_redirect');
        $redirect = $customer_redirect;
    } else {

        //Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
        $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
    }
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wp_woo_custom_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

If you feel comfortable working with plugin or without code? You can download and install my plugin "[WP WooCommerce Redirect](http://www.e2soft.com/blog/change-woocommerce-login-register-redirect-url/)"