# Redirect user after login/registration globally

Tags: redirect, login, user-registration, wp-redirect, wp-login-form

How it possible to redirect all users, even administrators after login to specific page? And also redirect users after successful registration? Any simplest way? For example I want to redirect users after login, to the "Updates" page of my website. And after registration, to the "Home" page of website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code adapted from: [Registration Redirect](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19692/how-to-redirect-a-sucessful-registration-to-a-page-template)

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'ckc_registration_redirect' );
function ckc_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url();
}
```

This code adapted from: [Login Redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'ckc_login_redirect' );
function ckc_login_redirect() {
    // Change this to the url to Updates page.
    return home_url( '/Updates' );
}
```

Add the code to the functions.php theme (or child theme) file.

Comment: Above codes goes in theme's `function.php`. When theme changed, again both pages redirect to their default locations. How we can redirect by changing WP core files?

Comment: Never change the core files. Changes will be removed when WordPress updates. You could do this from a plugin to make them theme independent.

Answer (score 1):

To add one more to the list for logout:

```
add_action('wp_logout','go_home');
function go_home(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To globally redirect after successful login, find this code in `wp-login.php`, under `<form name="loginform">` section.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_attr($redirect_to); ?>" />
```

and replace `<?php echo esc_attr($redirect_to); ?>` with your  URL where you want to redirect. The URL must start with `http://` and ends on `/`other wise page redirect to default location.

Do same thing form redirect after registration with in same file but under `<form name="registerform">` section.

---

Edit:

This method involves changing WordPress core code. It is rarely recommended by any serious WordPress programmer. [Proceed at your own risk.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files)

Answer (score 0):

With plugin:

- [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/)
- and a new one with fine features [Register Plus Redux](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/register-plus-redux/)

Enjoy!