# Wordpress not loggin user and redirecting after custom registration

Tags: redirect, login

I am trying to make custom registration form in my wordpress site , the form is registered successfully but i couldn't login the user after registration and redirect to a custom url.

**this is the code i have used**

```
<?php
$err = '';
$success = '';

global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;

if(isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $pwd1 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['pwd1']));
    $pwd2 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['pwd2']));
    $email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email']));
    $username = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['username']));

    if( $email == "" || $pwd1 == "" || $pwd2 == "" || $username == "") {
        $err = 'Please don\'t leave the required fields.';
    } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $err = 'Invalid email address.';
    } else if(email_exists($email) ) {
        $err = 'Email already exist.';
    } else if($pwd1 <> $pwd2 ){
        $err = 'Password do not match.';
    } else {
        $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
        if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $error_string = $user_id->get_error_message();
            $err = $error_string;
        } else {
            do_action('user_register', $user_id);
            wp_set_current_user($user_id); // set the current wp user
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
            wp_redirect( get_home_url() ); 

            $success = 'You\'re successfully registered';
        }
    }

}
?>
```

- I have tried using javascript for redirecting ,it doesn't help.
- what i'am missing here?

I want redirect by login the user after registration

Comment: [Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98382/147428) to similar question

Answer (score 0):

You can add that redirection to your `functions.php`, you have to use the `registration_redirect` hook:

```
function wpse_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url( '/page' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_registration_redirect' );
```